# vb.net set images to picturebox one by one

Tags: vb.net, picturebox

I have performed the following steps in my vb.net code:

1. From a text file and get the lines contain the values I want, in my case, I need the last value as "Group"
2. Create a picturebox array, the number of pictureboxes is the number from step 1. 1 row has 2 pictureboxes.

After that I want to set the image read from the text file to the pictureboxes 1 by 1 ( the picture name is the 2nd value.jpg), but I haven't found a proper way to do this.

Any advice on it?

My text file is as follows:

[image]

My code till now is:

```
    Private PicBoxArray(9) As PictureBox        

    Dim value0 As String
    Dim value1 As String
    Dim value2 As String
    Dim value3 As String

    Dim fileName As String = "D:\local\MyTest1.txt"
    Dim subString1 As String = "Group"
    Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
    For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(i).Contains(subString1) Then
            count1 += 1
    end if
    Next

    For i = 1 To count1
        PicBoxArray(i) = New PictureBox
        With PicBoxArray(i)
            .Tag = i
            .Size = New Size(330, 280)
            If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .Location = New Point(430, 80 + 300 * ((i - 2) / 2))                   
            Else
                .Location = New Point(80, 80 + 300 * ((i - 1) / 2))
            End If

            .Parent = Me
            .Visible = True
        End With
    Next

  Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                FileIO.TextFieldParser("D:\PUB_GIS_Tagging\local\MyTest.txt")

        Dim lineCount = File.ReadAllLines("D:\PUB_GIS_Tagging\local\MyTest.txt").Length

        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                value0 = currentRow(0)  
                value1 = currentRow(1)  
                value2 = currentRow(2) 
                value3 = currentRow(3)


   If value3 = "Group"
       '======= put the picture from PicBoxArray(1) to PicBoxArray(count1) i by 1========
       '====================== I am stuck here=============
   End if 

   Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
         FileIO.MalformedLineException
         MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
                "is not valid and will be skipped.")
   End Try
 End While
End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i assume you want to read a line from your file and then set the picture from that line to your first picturebox and then read the next line and set the next picture to the next picturebox?

```
Dim linecounter as Integer = 0 
While Not MyReader.EndOfData
        Try
            currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

            value0 = currentRow(0)  
            value1 = currentRow(1)  
            value2 = currentRow(2) 
            value3 = currentRow(3)


If value3 = "Group" Then
    PicBoxArray(linecounter).ImageLocation = "C:\vb_test\" & value1 & ".pdf.jpg" 
    linecounter += 1
End if 
next
```

Comment: Hi Index, thanks a lot for the answer. I put the code in my application like follows:  For i = 1 To count1
                            PicBoxArray(i).ImageLocation = "C:\vb_test\" & value4 & ".pdf.jpg"
                        Next,  but every time read a line, all the images will change together to the new line value. I think there still something wrong in my code, could you please look at this? thank you!